# mouseMoved Event can't get location of cursor

Tags: java, swing

newbie in here

this is my code and i wanna when cursor get into green jpanel (here is "p2"), program will have another jpanel (here is "p1") to show some information about Object. (like a ToolTip)

But when cursor get into JPanel p2 ... mouseMove can't get location of the cursor ... It only work when I remove JPanel p2 . Please help me guys

Note: It's still work on border of JPanel p2;

```js
import javax.management.Attribute;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet.FontAttribute;

import org.w3c.dom.events.EventTarget;
import org.w3c.dom.events.MouseEvent;
import org.w3c.dom.views.AbstractView;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator;
import java.util.Locale;

public class InterfaceSubject extends JFrame {

 public JPanel contentPane, p1, p2;
 public JButton bt1;
 public JLabel lb2;
 public JTextPane tp1, tp2, tp3;

 public InterfaceSubject() {
  this.setResizable(false);
  setTitle("Demo");
  setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  setBounds(100, 20, 1024, 768);

  bt1 = new JButton();
  p1 = new JPanel();
  p1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p1.setBackground(Color.yellow);


  p2 = new JPanel();
  GridLayout gr = new GridLayout();
  gr.setColumns(1);
  gr.setRows(3);
  p2.setLayout(gr);

  lb2 = new JLabel();

  tp1 = new JTextPane();
  tp1.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
  tp1.setBackground(Color.green);
  tp1.setText("MMH: 212121");

  tp2 = new JTextPane();
  tp2.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
  tp2.setBackground(Color.green);
  tp2.setText("Tên MH: Hello");

  tp3 = new JTextPane();
  tp3.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
  tp3.setBackground(Color.green);
  tp3.setText("TC : 1");

  contentPane = new ImagePanel(
    new ImageIcon("images\\formtkb.jpg").getImage());
  contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

  p2.setBounds(60, 121, 125, 75);

  p2.add(tp1);
  p2.add(tp2);
  p2.add(tp3);

  contentPane.add(p2);

  setContentPane(contentPane);

  contentPane.setLayout(null);

  this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

   @Override
   public void mouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent arg0) {

    if ((arg0.getX()) >= (60) && arg0.getX() <= (60 + 125)) {
     if ((arg0.getY()) >= (121 + 25)
       && (arg0.getY()) <= (121 + 100)) {
      p1.setVisible(true);
      p1.setBounds(new Rectangle(arg0.getPoint(),
        new Dimension(200, 200)));
      lb2.setText(arg0.getX() + " / " + arg0.getY());

      p1.add(lb2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      contentPane.add(p1);
     } else {
      p1.setVisible(false);
     }
    } else {
     p1.setVisible(false);
    }

   }

   @Override
   public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
  });

 }

}

class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

 /**
   * 
   */
 private Image img;

 public ImagePanel(String img) {
  this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());
 }

 public ImagePanel(Image img) {
  this.img = img;
  Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
  setPreferredSize(size);
  setMinimumSize(size);
  setMaximumSize(size);
  setSize(size);
  setLayout(null);

 }

 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  g.drawImage(img, 0, 100, null);
 }

}
```

Comment: *"mouseMove can't get location of the cursor ... It only work when I remove JPanel p2"*  It is most likely that the panel is consuming the mouse events that would have been destined for the component beneath it.  One common fix is to add the listener to each component that needs to detect mouse events.

Comment: BTW - this seems to have *nothing* to do with [tag:javascript].

Answer (score 0):

add mouseMotionListener for your panels. like

```
    p1.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent arg0) {

            }
    });


    p2.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent arg0) {

            }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry but it's not work ... please find another way ... Thanks for your ans